# MYSQLI Ошибка вывода | Выводит только первую запись из DB

Tags: php, mysqli

Почему-то у меня PHP выводит только первое значение из бд, как решить?

```
$mysql = mysqli_connect($c['host'], $c['user'], $c['pass'], $c['db']);
$sql=mysqli_query($mysql,"SELECT * FROM dle_users WHERE user_id = '".$_COOKIE['dle_user_id']."'");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
    $pro = mysqli_connect($c['host'], $c['user'], $c['pass'], $c['db']);
    $prod=mysqli_query($pro, "SELECT * FROM dle_products  ");
    while($pdo = mysqli_fetch_array($prod, MYSQLI_BOTH)){
        if(file_exists('buy/mc/'.$pdo['item_id'].'.png')){
           $img = 'buy/mc/'.$pdo['item_id'].'.png';
        } else {
           $img = 'buy/mc/unknown.png';
        }
        $image = '<img src="'.$img.'" alt="'.$pdo['name'].'">';
        echo'
        <i class="fa fa-info" aria-hidden="true"   title="'.$pdo['description'].'"></i>
       '.$pdo['name'].'<br />
       '.$image.'<br />


'.$pdo['price'].' '.$valet.' за '.$pdo['amount'].' шт';
        }
        mysqli_close($pro);
     }
     mysqli_close($mysql);
```

Код вроде оформил правильно, но всё-равно выводит только первое значение из БД

Comment: `mysqli_query($mysql,"SELECT * FROM dle_users WHERE user_id = '".$_COOKIE['dle_user_id']."'");` нельзя подставлять значения, пришедшие от пользователя прямо в запрос. Нужно использовать подготовленные запросы. `$pro = mysqli_connect($c['host'], $c['user'], $c['pass'], $c['db']);` делать второе соединение в данном случае бессмысленно и беспощадно. `while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){` значение `$row` нигде не используется. Проверка на существование пользователя проводится несколько иначе. `mysqli_close($pro);` закрытие соединения делать не обязательно (за исключением редких случаев).

Comment: Поправил все свои баги

Comment: Но, всё-равно выводится только первая запись

Comment: Обновите ваш вопрос с исправленным кодом. Выведите значение `mysqli_num_rows($prod);`. Чему оно равно?

Comment: потому что user_id в базе всего один скорее всего, и нет цикла для извлечения из $prod

Comment: Всё, решил проблему, в коде который прислал я - нет ошибок, ибо я прислал немного изменёную его форму, на главной в цикле происходил вывод, в который был подключен шаблон продукта, который я подключил при помощи include_once, хотя надо было просто include

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`mysqli_query($mysql,"SELECT * FROM dle_users WHERE user_id = '".$_COOKIE['dle_user_id']."'");` нельзя подставлять значения, пришедшие от пользователя прямо в запрос. Нужно использовать подготовленные запросы. `$pro = mysqli_connect($c['host'], $c['user'], $c['pass'], $c['db']);` делать второе соединение в данном случае бессмысленно и беспощадно. `while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){` значение $row нигде не используется. Проверка на существование пользователя проводится несколько иначе. `mysqli_close($pro);` закрытие соединения делать не обязательно (за исключением редких случаев)